# Unable to compile C Program

Tags: c, macos, gcc, netbeans, compiler-errors

I am working on NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905) on MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2011) with (OSX 10.10.5) with Compiler version Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72) /Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0.

I want to compile following codes:
stack/main

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
 * 
  */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

push(1.2);
(void)printf("On Stack");


//return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

stack/src/stack.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

/* initialize stack for float values */
static float stack[STACK_LENGTH] = { 0.0 };

/* 
 * increase stack and push new float into stack[0]
 * params:
 *  float > new value to push to position 0
 * return:
 *  void
 */
void push(float new) {
    /* to do */
    if(pos<STACK_LENGTH){
        stack[pos++]=new;
    }else{
        (void)printf("Stack-Overflow\n");
    }
}

/* 
 * pop float at position 0 and decrease stack 
 * params: void
 * return: float > value at position 0
 */
float pop(void) {
    /* to do */
    if(pos>0){
        stack[pos--];
    } else{
        (void)printf("Stack-leak\n");
    }
}

/* 
 * get stack at pos 
 * params: int > stack position 
 * return: float > value at position pos
 */
float get(int pos) {
    /* to do */
    float value;
    return value = stack[pos];
}

/* 
 * set float value in stack at pos
 * params:
 *  float > value to set at position pos
 *  int > stack position 
 * return:
 *  void
 */
void set(float value, int pos) {
    /* to do */
    stack[pos] = value;
}

/* 
 * list stack to console
 * params:
 *  void 
 * return:
 *  int > number of characters printed
 */
int list(void) {
    /* to do */
    return 0;
}

/* 
 * clear stack
 * params: void
 * return: void 
 */
void clear(void) {
    /* to do */
    float stack[15]=  {0.0}; 
}
```

stack/src/stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_

/* Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* stack size */
#define STACK_LENGTH 15

/* global variables*/
static float stack[STACK_LENGTH];
static int pos = 0;

/*function declaration*/
void push(float);
float pop();
float get(int);
void set(float, int);
int list();
void clear();



#endif /* STACK_H_ */
```

When I run this statement:

> gcc -c demo_stack.c

I get this error:

```
>fatal error: 'stack.h' file not found
>#include "stack.h"
>         ^
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you that he has not enough information to find your file `stack.h`. You have to add an include path to your compiler command line. For gcc this is usually done with a `-I directoryNameGoesHere` option.

Comment: Do you mean like this: gcc -c -l stack/src/ demo_stack.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the files are in different folders and a compiler can't read your mind and your intents:

```
stack/src/stack.c
stack/src/stack.h
stack/main/demo_stack.c?
```

First of all if you need to compile both c files if you want to link them together and produce an executable, since the file with main() function refers function `push` which is declared in `stack.h` but defines in `stack.c`. Then you need to tell your compiler that the path that includes `stack.h` should be considered when compiling your main file. Your final build command should look something like

```
clang -c -I../stack demo_stack.c ../stack/stack.c
```

Comment: I have made the changes and I created the .o-files. now I get this: `main root$ gcc -c demo_stack.c
root$ gcc -o stack.exe demo_stack.o                              
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_push", referenced from:
_main in demo_stack.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Got it! gcc stack.o demo_stack.o -o demo_stack